# Filter Kendo ListView with search bar and dropdowns

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I have a `Kendo ListView` on my page and I would like to be able to use a custom search bar and two `Kendo DropDownLists` to allow the user to filter the `ListView`.

I have no problem filtering while just using the search bar or just using the dropdowns but I am running into issues trying to figure out how to be able to filter the data using all three at the same time.

For example, I want to be able to type something into the search and have it filter the search term. Then with the results that are shown, I want to be able to filter those results down by using either dropdown.

I've got a full example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRpoag

To test it out, type into the search bar "test". You'll notice that it filters down to one result. Now expand the "Product Type" dropdown and select "Type 1". Notice how it then shows all products with that type? It should show no results because I only want to apply that filter on top of the current ones.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue when trying to filter grids using multiple multi select drop downs and manage to resolve using the answer. [Check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780495/custom-filtering-with-multi-select-drop-downs) see if it helps. :)

Comment: Your text box does not trigger the filter when you are removing a filter with a backspace and other keys. I am not able to go through the code in it's entirety, however,  I would suggest that you condense the logic into one filter method and pass in the grid or the data source and have all change event handlers call the one filter function that will check all fields and build the filter and apply it to the data source.

Comment: I read you last paragraph and followed you instructions. You are handling all events properly, however, your product drop down event does not look for the absence or presence of a filter on name. You have to handle both or all three filters in one function for this to work the way you would like.

Comment: @Sandman Thanks so much for the link/suggestion! I adapted your function to meet my needs and it works perfectly now. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Sandman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6224482/sandman) for providing me with a link to his question which was very similar to mine and which he was able to find a solution for. I have changed his solution a little bit so that it would work for me. [Original Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780495/custom-filtering-with-multi-select-drop-downs).

```
function applyClientFilters() {
    var listView = $("#ProductsList").data("kendoListView");
    var listViewDataSource = listView.dataSource;
    // clear existing datasource
    listViewDataSource.filter([]);
    // extract selected items from each of the dropdown controls and the search box
    var productType = $("#ProductTypeDropDown").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    var therapeuticClass = $("#TherapeuticClassDropDown").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    var searchString = $(".search-filter").val();
    // setup filter object (using and logic)
    var filter = {
        logic: "and",
        filters: [] // ready for filter from each of the dropdowns and search bar
    };
    // push new filter into array of filters with or logic on each filter
    if (productType.length > 0) {
        var productTypeFilter = {
            logic: "or",
            filters: [
                { field: "ProductTypeId", operator: "equals", value: productType }
            ]
        };
        filter.filters.push(productTypeFilter);
    }


    if (therapeuticClass.length > 0) {
        var therapeuticClassFilter = {
            logic: "or",
            filters: [
                {
                    field: "TherapeuticClasses",
                    operator: function (itemValue, value) {
                        return itemValue &&
                            itemValue.find(function (item) {
                                if (item.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                    },
                    value: therapeuticClass
                }
            ]
        };
        filter.filters.push(therapeuticClassFilter);
    }

    if (searchString.length > 0) {
        var searchFilter = {
            logic: "or",
            filters: [
                { field: "Name", operator: "startswith", value: searchString },
                { field: "ProductTypeDisplay", operator: "startswith", value: searchString },
                { field: "NdcCode", operator: "startswith", value: searchString },
                {
                    field: "TherapeuticClasses",
                    operator: function(itemValue, value) {
                        return itemValue &&
                            itemValue.find(function(item) {
                                // If a therapeutic class name matches search then return true
                                if (item.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                    },
                    value: searchString
                }
            ]
        };
        filter.filters.push(searchFilter);
    }

    // apply filter query to datasource
    listViewDataSource.query({
        filter: filter
    });
}
```

Then I just call the `applyClientFilters()` function in the change event of each dropdown and search box and the filtering works great.